# How to select one table column in MS Word printed PDF document

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I've got a lot of PDF like this:

```
Jogn Doe                    Carol Black
Street 1                    Street 2
City                        OtherCity
```

The data in MS Word 2010 source are formated as a two column table.

I would like to be able to simply select all data of only one recipient(select one column) like this:

[image]

But it's possible only when opened as MS Word document. If I printed the document into PDF (MS Word 2010 default PDF printer), it selects the whole rows at once.

[image]

How should I structure the data in MS Word document to be able to select it this way also in PDF after printing?
(without using CTRL and select part of each rows separately of course)

The Only think I came with was "two column layout", but that totally breaks if you add something to the first column (the addresses are not vertically at the same level then).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the default PDF printer with my install of Word 2010 right now, but when I went to "File\Save & Send\Create PDF/XPS Document" and selected PDF, **using Word text boxes worked** fine for me. I set the wrapping to inline with text and just copy-pasted a blank box until I had the number I needed.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I could also just merge the rows into one and use "enter" as separator (without using Word text boxes). I just didn't get it at the first time trying to find some super-solution.